# Solr index removing stopwords does not seem to work

Tags: indexing, solr

I would like to remove stopwords from my index during indexing and query but somehow the words within the stopwords.txt do not seem to be removed from my index (I can still use these in a query and get result hits with them).

Here is my schema.xml:

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"         positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"         synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
            -->
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"         ignoreCase="true"         words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"         generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"         catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>        
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory"         protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory"         synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"         words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"         generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0"         catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>        
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory"         protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
      <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
      <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"         required="true" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="post_content" type="text" indexed="true"         stored="true"/>
      <field name="post_title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
      <field name="post_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
      <field name="_text_" type="text" indexed="true"         stored="false"          multiValued="true" termVectors="true"                 termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
```

I am using Solr 6.0.

Thanks for any advice,

Sabine

Comment: Does the file with same name exist? Do you have those words in the file stopwords.txt?

Comment: Sorry for bothering the community - I solved the problem myself by adding "format="snowball""

Comment: no problem...it may help somebody else...:)

Answer (score 0):

By default the file `stopwords.txt` does not have any stop words in it.

You can check the same in any of the configSet given by Solr.

But if you check the conf/lang folder , you will find many stopword files.

You can use whichever is applicable for you as per your language.

For the testing purpose you can copy the stopwords from the `stopwords_en.txt` file and paste in the file `stopward.txt` in the path `configsets/basic_configs/conf/`. Here configset may be different for you. It depends which one you have used.